# Jenkins SSH launch method

Tags: jenkins, ssh, connection

I set up Jenkins controller and want to connect agent to it. When I choose *Launch agent by connecting it to the controller* in *Launch method* there is no problem. When I restart service in agent it connects to master correctly, but I would like to launch it via SSH so that the connection will be more secure and reconnect with no problem if agent restarts. What should I do apart from selecting *Launch agent via SSH* ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNGwi.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, connect to the target computer through the command line, e.g.:

```
ssh jenkins@LAPTOP-ML8M5TVB
```

When you are able to connect with the command line, create a credential in Jenkins with the private key you used for ssh to work, and select that credential in the node configuration.

Then, disconnect and reconnect the node.